# Is a Giant Spider rideable?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape, mount

Some friends and I were in a coliseum-style arena and needed to get out. We were contemplating leaving through the stands on the back of my Druid's Giant Spider Wildshape but ultimately decided against it.

This still leaves a question that will probably come up again in this campaign:

**Can you ride a giant spider, and, if so, how many people can ride it?**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Sure, a giant spider can be a mount.

Here is what the *Player's Handbook* says about the eligibility of a mount in the Mounted Combat section (p. 198):

> A willing creature that is at least one size larger than you and that has an appropriate anatomy can serve as a mount.

The giant spider is Large size, and humanoids are Medium size, so the size restriction is  met.

The wildshaped druid is supposedly willing, so the willingness restriction is met.

If the DM rules that a spider's anatomy is appropriate (I would), then the anatomy restriction is met, although a DM might rule otherwise.

As long as you have the support of the DM, then yes the wildshaped druid can act as a mount.

## Anything beyond that is up to the DM.

There are no rules for multiple creatures riding a single mount. The rules for Mounted Combat heavily imply a single rider per mount by omission of any rules about multiple riders, but there's nothing that explicitly prohibits it. So, the DM could allow multiple riders, but they would have to create their own rulings, because the rules are silent.

Comment: If your DM is leery about using a Giant Spider as a mount...check out the Steeder. Big tarantula-like spider that is canonically used by Duergar as a Mount (see Out of the Abyss page 231 or [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/female-steeder) on dndbeyond.)

Answer (score 13):

## Yes

Your standard [Giant Spider](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/giant-spider) is a Large CR 1 beast, which makes it eligible for a Circle of the Moon druid to Wildshape into. It being Large also makes it available for a Medium or smaller creature (like most PCs) to mount. (see PHB pg 198: Mounted Combat)

There is no limitation on how many creatures can ride a mount at once (Mounted Combat rules imply 1 rider but there is nothing definite), although the creature should have a limit on carrying capacity and your DM should overrule any obvious shenanigans.

For reference, a Riding Horse or Camel has similar size, strength, and constitution as a Giant Spider and can carry 480lbs.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning weights!

I would mention that *Animal Friendship* could be an option for an actual, non-druid Giant Spider since it has an int of 2, assuming a GM rules that a charmed spider would be a willing mount.

Comment: @Hamstertron I don't see this question as being about willingness. Certainly that would be required for the PCs the mount any given spider, but the question is asking if a Giant Spider is able to become a mount in the first place.

Comment: *A willing creature that is at least one size larger than you and that has an appropriate anatomy can serve as a mount.*

Notwithstanding the willingness of a PC druid, a wild Giant Spider may meet every criteria for being a mount except willingness due to it's hostility.

Comment: A Riding Horse is STR 16. A Giant Spider is only 14, and has a limit of 420 pounds. This is _maybe_ enough for two Medium creatures if they don't have too much gear.